# Probability of numbers

Tags: probability

Given random decimal digits, what is probability that there are unique digits?

Answer (score 2):

The number of sequences of $10^6$ digits equally distributed is given by the multinomial coefficient
$$\binom{10^6}{\underbrace{10^5,10^5,\ldots,10^5}_{10\text{ times}}}$$

And the total number of sequences is $10^{10^6}$. Then, the probability is

$$\frac{(10^6)!}{(10^5)!^{10}\cdot10^{10^6}}$$

Comment: Or about $3.91\cdot 10^{-61}$